# RecyclerView sets wrong MotionLayout state for its items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

First: I created a sample project showing this problem. By now I begin to think that this is a bug in either RecyclerView or MotionLayout.

https://github.com/muetzenflo/SampleRecyclerView

This project is set up a little bit different than what is described below: It uses data binding to toggle between the MotionLayout states. But the outcome is the same. Just play around with toggling the state and swiping between the items. Sooner than later you'll come upon a ViewHolder with the wrong MotionLayout state.

---

So the main problem is:

### ViewHolders outside of the screen are not updated correctly when transition from one MotionLayout state to another.

---

**So here is the problem / What I've found so far:**

I am using a RecyclerView.

It has only 1 item type which is a MotionLayout (so every item of the RV is a MotionLayout).

This MotionLayout has 2 states, let's call them State `big` and State `small`

All items should always have the same State. So whenever the state is switched for example from `big` => `small` then ALL items should be in `small` from then on.

But what happens is that the state changes to `small` and most(!) of the items are also updated correctly. But one or two items are always left with the old State. I am pretty sure it has to do with recycled ViewHolders. These steps produce the issue reliably when using the adapter code below (not in the sample project):

1. swipe from item 1 to the right to item 2
2. change from `big` to `small`
3. change back from `small` to `big`
4. swipe from item 2 to the left to item 1
   => item 1 is now in the `small` state, but should be in the `big` state

Additional findings:

- After step 4 if I continue swiping to the left, there comes 1 more item in the `small` state (probably the recycled ViewHolder from step 4). After that no other item is wrong.
- Starting from step 4, I continue swiping for a few items (let's say 10) and then swipe all the way back, no item is in the wrong `small` state anymore. The faulty recycled ViewHolder seems to be corrected then.

What did I try?

- I tried to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever the transition has completed
- I tried keeping a local Set of created ViewHolders to call the transition on them directly
- I tried to use data-binding to set the `motionProgress` to the MotionLayout
- I tried to set `viewHolder.isRecycable(true|false)` to block recycling during the transition
- I searched [this great in-depth article about RVs](https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-404ba3453714#8179) for hint what to try next

Anyone had this problem and found a good solution?

Just to avoid confusion: `big` and `small` does not indicate that I want to collapse or expand each item! It is just a name for different arrangement of the motionlayouts' children.

```
class MatchCardAdapter() : DataBindingAdapter<Match>(DiffCallback, clickListener) {

    private val viewHolders = ArrayList<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()

    private var direction = Direction.UNDEFINED

    fun setMotionProgress(direction: MatchCardViewModel.Direction) {
        if (this.direction == direction) return

        this.direction = direction

        viewHolders.forEach {
            updateItemView(it)
        }
    }

    private fun updateItemView(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder.adapterPosition >= 0) {
            val motionLayout = viewHolder.itemView as MotionLayout
            when (direction) {
                Direction.TO_END -> motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
                Direction.TO_START -> motionLayout.transitionToStart()
                Direction.UNDEFINED -> motionLayout.transitionToStart()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataBindingViewHolder<Match>, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item, clickListener)

        val itemView = holder.itemView
        if (itemView is MotionLayout) {
            if (!viewHolders.contains(holder)) {
                viewHolders.add(holder)
            }

            updateItemView(holder)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: DataBindingViewHolder<Match>) {
        if (holder.adapterPosition >= 0 && viewHolders.contains(holder)) {
            viewHolders.remove(holder)
        }
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your onBindViewHolderMethod ?

Comment: @Rinat I added the important parts of the Adapter. This is my current implementation.

Comment: I spent several hours trying different approaches, but all failed. Perhaps, you should start looking for alternative to MotionLayout for achieving your states.

Comment: thx, I went the same road :) I will probably post an issue in the google tracker soon.

Comment: I created an issue on the google tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162811653

Comment: yeah I agree there's lots of weird things I saw when tried to work around some of the issues. Specifically, `setProgress`, `setInterpolatedProgress` and `transitionToStart` could use more documentation for when and how they should be used.

Comment: I have similar issue with motionLayout. 
I have two tabs with Recyclers and list items have MotionLayout. 
When I transition from A -> B and switch tabs, sometimes I see state A again when I return back. 
It seems some bug in MotionLayout.

Comment: Jepp, by now I am almost certain that it is a bug when combining RV and ML. If you click the star in the upper-left corner of the google issue tracker link, then they may pick this one up sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I made some progress but this is not a final solution, it has a few quirks to polish. Like the animation from end to start doesn't work properly, it just jumps to the final position.

https://github.com/fmatosqg/SampleRecyclerView/commit/907ec696a96bb4a817df20c78ebd5cb2156c8424

Some things that I changed but are not relevant to the solution, but help with finding the problem:

- made duration 1sec
- more items in recycler view
- recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0) to try to keep as few unseen items as possible, although if you track it closely you know they tend to stick around
- eliminated data binding for handling transitions. Because I don't trust it in view holders in general, I could never make them work without a bad side-effect
- upgraded constraint library with `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1"`

Going into details about what made it work better:

**all calls to motion layout are done in a `post` manner**

```
    //    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929153/when-manually-set-progress-to-motionlayout-it-clear-all-constraints
    fun safeRunBlock(block: () -> Unit) {

        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(motionLayout)) {
            block()
        } else {
            motionLayout.post(block)
        }

    }
```

**Compared actual vs desired properties**

```
    val goalProgress =
            if (currentState) 1f
            else 0f
    val desiredState =
                if (currentState) motionLayout.startState
                else motionLayout.endState

 safeRunBlock {
            startTransition(currentState)
        }
 
 if (motionLayout.progress != goalProgress) {

    if (motionLayout.currentState != desiredState) {

        safeRunBlock {
            startTransition(currentState)
        }

    }
 }
```

This would be the full class of the partial solution

```
class DataBindingViewHolder<T>(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    val motionLayout: MotionLayout =
        binding.root.findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.root_item_recycler_view)
            .also {
                it.setTransitionDuration(1_000)
                it.setDebugMode(DEBUG_SHOW_PROGRESS or DEBUG_SHOW_PATH)
            }

    var lastPosition: Int = -1


    fun bind(item: T, position: Int, layoutState: Boolean) {

        if (position != lastPosition)
            Log.i(
                "OnBind",
                "Position=$position lastPosition=$lastPosition - $layoutState "
            )



        lastPosition = position

        setMotionLayoutState(layoutState)

        binding.setVariable(BR.item, item)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    //    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929153/when-manually-set-progress-to-motionlayout-it-clear-all-constraints
    fun safeRunBlock(block: () -> Unit) {

        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(motionLayout)) {
            block()
        } else {
            motionLayout.post(block)
        }

    }

    fun setMotionLayoutState(currentState: Boolean) {
        
        val goalProgress =
            if (currentState) 1f
            else 0f

        safeRunBlock {
            startTransition(currentState)
        }

        if (motionLayout.progress != goalProgress) {

            val desiredState =
                if (currentState) motionLayout.startState
                else motionLayout.endState

            if (motionLayout.currentState != desiredState) {
                Log.i("Pprogress", "Desired doesn't match at position $lastPosition")
                safeRunBlock {
                    startTransition(currentState)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun startTransition(currentState: Boolean) {
        if (currentState) {
            motionLayout.transitionToStart()
        } else {
            motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: added constraint layout version

Comment: thx for your work! I'll check it out over the weekend.

Comment: Hi, I had a look at your solution and the `safeRunBlock` is a good approach. The flickering is coming from `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I had the same issue in my tests. The question is not answered yet, but I upvoted your answer, so you should get the boundy implicitly if someone else gives you a 2nd upvote.